# Undefined index for max function not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing problem with my php code. I have already tried Stack Overflow suggestions, but that code doesn't properly work. Here I am using `max` and `min` functions. Also trying function `mysql_fetch_rows()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. It shows me the error `undefined index:facilities_total in line...` I also point out my error in below code. Please suggest how to correct this.

**This is my php with mysql query**

```
$sqlMax= "SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,max(facility_rating.facilities_total) 
    AS MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL 
    FROM facility_rating LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_detail
    on facility_rating.project_id = projects_detail.project_id
    group by facility_rating.facilities_total DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultMax=mysql_query($sqlMax);
echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";
while($rowsMax=mysql_fetch_array($resultMax)){
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$rowsMax['Project_name'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>".$rowsMax['facilities_total'] . "</td> "; //error undefined index:facilities_total
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If in doubt, use var_dump($rowsMax) so you can see what you are actually getting.  It's quicker than asking on SO ;)

Comment: Thanks to all of you.now my code is run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "<td>".$rowsMax['MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL'] . "</td> ";
```

Instead of

```
echo "<td>".$rowsMax['facilities_total'] . "</td> ";
```

In your sql your are using alias for `facilities_total`, so rows are fetched with  field name `MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL` instead of `facilities_total`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have already trying this Code .Still it shows error undefined index:MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL . Thats why i am posted this questions here.Tell me where is wrong i am ?

Comment: Actually its my browser problem.When i run in another browser then it runs fine.Thanking You

Answer (score 2):

As seen you are giving alias in your query and you are using column names in your php code:

```
$sqlMax= "SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,max(facility_rating.facilities_total) 
    AS MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL 
    FROM facility_rating LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_detail
    on facility_rating.project_id = projects_detail.project_id
    group by facility_rating.facilities_total DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultMax=mysql_query($sqlMax);
echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";
while($rowsMax=mysql_fetch_array($resultMax)){
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>".$rowsMax['Project_name'] . "</td> ";
    // Fix: Changed 'facilities_total' to 'MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL' below.
    echo "<td>".$rowsMax['MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL'] . "</td> "; //error undefined index:facilities_total
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have already trying this Code .Still it shows undefined index:MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL . Thats why i am posted this questions here.Tell me where is wrong i am ?

Comment: Try to print_r($rowsMax) in while loop and see what array you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL names the output column here:

```
 AS MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL
```

So the PHP variable you want will be

```
$rowsMax['MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have already trying this Code .Still it shows error undefined index:MAX_FACILITIES_TOTAL . Thats why i am posted this questions here.Tell me where is wrong i am ?

Comment: Then please update your question to include the best version of your code, not one with this obvious mistake.